# javascript setAttribute function not allowing units

Tags: javascript, svg, transform, percentage, setattribute

When I try to set the transform property using javascript, I can put values with no units in and the function works great.

```
document.getElementById("allnotes").setAttribute('transform','translate(0,10)');
```

However, when I try to put in a unit, the function does nothing.

```
document.getElementById("allnotes").setAttribute('transform','translate(0,10pt)');
document.getElementById("allnotes").setAttribute('transform','translate(0,10px)');
document.getElementById("allnotes").setAttribute('transform','translate(0,10%)');
```

How can I use the setAttribute function and put in % as my unit rather than a fixed amount?  And when no unit is specified, what unit is used by default?  *Edit: A little more background on this is that I am making a translation on a "g" element of an inline svg file.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure y it should not work - I've tried it on FF21 and it works. What Browser are you testing on?

Comment: I am using internet explorer 11.

Comment: works fine for me on IE 9 - (I don't have IE 11). You can check the attribute value with getAttribute('transform');

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
/* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
document.getElementById("allnotes").style.webkitTransform = "translate(0,10%)"; 

/* IE 9 */
document.getElementById("allnotes").style.msTransform = "translate(0,10%)"; 

/* No vendor prefix */
document.getElementById("allnotes").style.transform = "translate(0,10%)";
```

You can specify any (valid) unit you like.

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hibbard_eu/w3eLA/)**

Comment: Thank you.  The px and pt units appear to work great with this solution, but not %.  When I use %, nothing happens.

Comment: Works for me in Chrome. Are you sure you don't have any syntax errors? Here's an updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hibbard_eu/w3eLA/14/) .

Comment: When I look at your fiddle code, it works great, but when I change my code, nothing happens when I use the .style.transform.  What I am modifying is a "g" element with an inline svg file.  I am able to do this using setAttribute with no unit, but I want to make it % based as the svg is dynamically sized based on the device.  Does the .style.transform not work on svg elements?

Comment: I think you should be using the vendor prefix for IE: `style.msTransform`, but I'm afraid I'm on Linux, so testing could be problematic. Could you maybe make a fiddle where we can see it not working?

Comment: Jack,It took a bit to figure out the fiddle, but here is the code I am using.  http://jsfiddle.net/slayerofgiants/3j2WR/14/  The transform/translate errors when I try to put in units.

Comment: It seems you are still using `setAttribute`. I was meaning more of a concise fiddle where using `style.msTransform` doesn't work. However, as previously mentioned, I don't have easy access to IE, so testing might be difficult.